# Pigeonhole problem: Placing different types of UIImages into UIImageViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, algorithm, math, combinatorics

Let's say I have 10 boxes, and 4 different types of colored balls: black, blue, red, green. I would like to distribute different colored balls among the 10 boxes in roughly equal proportions. For instance, an acceptable solution would be to place 2 black, 2 blue, 3 red, and 3 green balls among the 10 boxes.

Now, to be more specific, let's say I have 10 UIImageViews, and a variable amount of types of UIImages (Facebook, Twitter, Flickr, etc.) to place into those UIImageViews. If I allow the user to turn off a certain type, there can be a variable number of types (all three, only two, only one, etc). Is there an efficient algorithm to distribute a variable number of types of objects into a static number of boxes?

The most straightforward way I can think of, but I feel like its terribly inefficient, is to have a for loop and just increment the number of each type of ball (UIImage) to place into a box (UIImageView) until the total number of balls is equal to the number of boxes. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I follow what you are asking.

It seems like you are looking for a type of div and mod math. Basically long division and remainders like we learn in 2nd grade. I am afraid I do not know the correct shorthand for this in objective-c. Hopefully someone can add that.

```
int numOfBoxes = 11;

int numOfBallTypes = 4;

int commonNumOfAllBallTypesInBoxes = numOfBoxes / numOfBallTypes; //this should be an int division result of 2

int numOfExtraBallTypes = numOfBoxes - (commonNumOfAllBallTypesInBoxes * numOfBallTypes); //this should be a remainder of 3)
```

Therefore you know to add `commonNumOfAllBallTypesInBoxes` of every ball type to each box. You then know to add one more ball for `numOfExtraBallTypes` out of `numOfBallTypes` ball types to each box.

**The results for the above are:**

numOfBoxes: 11

numOfBallTypes: 4

commonNumOfAllBallTypesInBoxes: 2

numOfExtraBallTypes: 3

**And it works for any dynamic:**

numOfBoxes: 73

numOfBallTypes: 11

commonNumOfAllBallTypesInBoxes: 6

numOfExtraBallTypes: 7

I hope this helps.